# Do any Android version 2.X tablets exists? Or did they come out later?

Tags: android

Need to know if I need to worry about people using this on my app

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most widely sold and used Android tablet is the Amazon Kindle Fire and it uses a custom version of Android 2.3. However it does not have the Android Market. There are a bunch of older tablets that use  2.x. Look at your users stats in the market to determine if you want to support it. In case of doubt I would say do it unless it is lots of effort.

Comment: Hey Manfred. My colleague has a Kindle fire and I fired it up to test the App, the user-agent on the Kindle Fire doesn't mention Android only Mac e.t.c so its currently getting blocked out by our user agent filter. It's a bit weird that its Android 2.3 but the user-agent doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1):

There were several tablets sold (and still are) running Android 2.x.

Comment: Damn this is unfortunate news, thanks for your post. I'll try and find a Android 2.X tablet emulator